attempting to setup remote desktop but computer keeps freezing
I got an HP 15-ac130ca with 1tb of storage and 8gb of ram freshly installed with ubuntu 24.04. Every time I enter remote desktop settings to set it up my whole computer crashes. Any suggestions?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

A suggestion: Try reinstalling the remote desktop server packages using
apt-get reinstall gnome-remote-desktop

I had a similar but less severe problem, which resolved itself when I reinstalled the gnome-remote-desktop packages.
For me, Only the Settings app froze, not the entire machine. But I have a 4-core CPU, and your HP 15-ac130ca is a 2-core, so it could still be the same problem (eg. a deadlock) that manifests itself differently.
A plain apt-get install gnome-remote-desktop indicated that all files were up-to-date and no changes were made, but apt-get reinstall gnome-remote-desktop still solved the problem.
Details about my problem (which may or may not be the same as yours)
Ubuntu 24.04 Fresh install. System 'Settings' freezes when going [System]-[Remote Desktop]

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
